# Ruby on Rails cant access instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

sorry for the lame question, but I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm trying to list all objects of a model when I'm rendering the 'new' view of another model and I'm getting an error

I have my cliente_controller.rb that has:

```
class ClientesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cliente, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /clientes/new
  def new
    @cliente = Cliente.new
    @advogados = Advogado.find(:all)
  end
```

and at my cliente/new.html.erb I have:

```
  <% @advogados.each do |advogado| %>
    <%= @advogado.nome %>
  <% end %>
```

and the error thrown is:

```
    undefined method `nome' for nil:NilClass
```

but when I do:

```
  <%= @advogados %>
```

It prints:

```
[#<Advogado id: 5, nome: "Adv1", created_at: "2014-05-02 13:58:33", updated_at: "2014-05-02 13:58:33">, #<Advogado id: 6, nome: "Adv2", created_at: "2014-05-02 13:58:48", updated_at: "2014-05-02 13:58:48">]
```

So @advogados is not null, but somehow I can't access the variables when looping through it. Any ideias?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= advogado.nome %>
```

Not

```
<%= @advogado.nome %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is iterating over your list of `@advogados` and storing each one in the variable `advogado` for the duration of the block.

Inside the block you should be using `advogado`, not `@advogado`. So call `advogado.nome`.

Answer (score 1):

Is `<%= advogado.nome %>` because you are redefined into the each.

Answer (score 1):

`@advogado.nome` should be `advogado.nome` , check this [instance variables](http://ruby.about.com/od/variables/a/Instance-Variables.htm) in ruby on rails

```
<% @advogados.each do |advogado| %>
   <%=advogado.nome%>
<% end %>
```